# Drush gives me "warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Tags: drush

I'm always using Drush to manage my Drupal websites. Now I got a new website, where another hosting company set up Drush, and it isn't working. Contacting them is a problem because of a time difference.

The problem is when I run the command: `drush selfupdate --debug`

I get the following error:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.19
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
GNU Wget 1.12 bouwde op linux-gnu.

+digest +ipv6 +nls +ntlm +opie +md5/openssl +https -gnutls +openssl
-iri

Wgetrc:
  /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale
Compileer: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc"
  -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -O2 -g -pipe -Wall
  -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector
  --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom
  -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-strict-aliasing
Link: gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions
  -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686
  -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-strict-aliasing
  -Wl,-z,relro -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz /usr/lib/libssl.so
  /usr/lib/libcrypto.so -ldl -lrt ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o
  gen-md5.o ../lib/libgnu.a

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Dit is vrije software: u mag het vrijelijk wijzigen en verder verspreiden.
De precieze licentie is GPLv3+: GNU GPL versie 3 of later.
Zie http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html voor de volledige tekst.
Er is GEEN GARANTIE, voor zover de wet dit toestaat.

Oorspronkelijk geschreven door Hrvoje Nikšić <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Tegenwoordig onderhouden door Micah Cowan <micah@cowan.name>.
Rapporteer gebreken in het programma (of suggesties) aan <bug-wget@gnu.org>;
meld fouten in de vertaling aan <vertaling@vrijschrift.org>.
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
PHP configuration     :  /usr/local/lib/php.ini 
Drush version         :  5.0-dev                
Drush configuration   :                         

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>/path/to/drush/includes/output.inc</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
```

Server: Apache2
Drupal version 6

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in Drush 5 and later, drush self-update only informs you of whether there is an update; this is no longer a mechanism for updating Drush.  In fact, this code is now broken, as it is set up to test for updates on drupal.org, whereas new releases are being made on GitHub.

Are you having other problems with Drush?  If so, the best route is probably to ask your ISP, who installed it for you.  You can also try installing the version that you want following the manual instructions in the Drush [README](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) file; basically, you just need to unpack the Drush release (or check out from git), and insure that the Drush you want to use appears first in your PATH.

You could also inform your ISP that Drush 6 is out, and is now the recommended version.  Ideally, they would then upgrade for you.  If you want to use Drupal 8, though, then you'll probably have to install from the master branch yourself.